# Scripts SQL contenidos en EXE

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo este escenario, un set de varios scripts que necesito esten contenidos en el EXE para evitar modificaciones de parte del usuario y que son:

1) creacion de la base de datos
2) inserts de los maestros
3) inserts de la data de prueba

Al ejecutarse deben retornar los errores, si los hubiese, en alguna variable para luego interpretarlos, no en un archivo de salida sino en una variable que me sera enviada mediante email por la aplicacion.

Estuve probando con process.start() y todo lo demas, pero la salida la envia a un texto

Hay forma de hacer que los errores los devuelva en variable del programa?

Gracias

Comment: Si te preocupa la seguridad, realmente tenerlos como scripts separados dentro del .exe a tenerlos dentro del código C# como sentencias, a nivel de seguridad ,no cambia nada. Realmente no es ni una buena práctica, ni tampoco seguro, ya que fácilmente se puede obtener de un fichero .exe su código fuente en el lenguaje intermedio de Microsoft (MSIL), como por ejemplo la herramienta Desensamblador MSIL incluido en el SDK de .NET y, sin saber MSIL, hay herramientas  de terceros que permiten traducir código MSIL a código fuente VB o C# como por ejemplo Redgate .NET Reflector

Comment: Por favor comparte el código que tienes para ver cual es el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución mejor que guardar el script en el ejecutable es guardarlo en la base de datos como procedimiento almacenado, de esta forma puedes ejecutarlos sin necesidad de tenerlos dentro del exe.